# Get tab completion in custom comint mode

Tags: emacs, tab-completion

I usually try to start CLI's (might not be defining it properly) using commands like:

```
(make-comint-in-buffer "PUTTY" nil "./plink.exe" nil "dbserver")
(make-comint-in-buffer "Python" nil "c:/Python26/python.exe" nil "-i")
(make-comint-in-buffer "Python" nil "c:/Python27/python.exe" nil "-i")
(make-comint-in-buffer "git" nil "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe" nil "--login" "-i")
```

Starting the above specially the first and the last in command prompt provides the facility of <kbd>tab</kbd> completion. But in `comint-mode` I don't seem to get this feature.

Entering <kbd>tab</kbd> adds a simple tab character under the point instead of passing it to the process and getting back the completion candidates. `comint-dynamic-complete` and <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't produce the desired result.

How can I utilize in above said feature in `comint-mode` running different processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

You need to write your own completion functions inside Emacs. These may pull info in from the external program, but you can't have direct access to the tab-completion provided by python or git etc.

### Long answer:

When you run `make-comint-in-buffer`, you are setting up the most basic setup for interactively sending and receiving data from an external process. Whenever you press `enter`, Emacs sends the current line to the underlying process, and then prints back the output from the process. The external process doesn't know what you're doing until Emacs sends a full line to it - no single characters are passed directly.

This is different from running the external program directly in a terminal. When you run python in a terminal, it interprets every character as you type it (or at least it can). So when you hit tab it knows to try to complete something. When you run python inside Emacs, Emacs is processing all of your input until you hit enter. Which means when you hit tab, Emacs just inserts a tab character, and python doesn't know to try and complete something.

Emacs can provide tab-completion for comint modes, but you need to build the completion targets on the Emacs side, you can't rely on the native completion of the external program. To get an idea of how this works, take a look at the completion functions in shell.el, which you can open with `M-x find-library shell`.

This isn't something you can do with a line or two of elisp. It's an important part of major-modes written to interact with external processes - things like ESS for R http://ess.r-project.org/

That said, if you dig into the guts of shell.el you may find enough code you can modify to get you started.

Comment: Lately I stumbled upon a pretty easy solution. Which works for `plink`(PUTTY) but not for Git-sh. Spawn the process with `comint`, then enable `term-char-mode` and your good to go.

Comment: Somewhere in the long answer would be great to have some elaboration into what the short answer describes: how to write a completion function that pulls info from the comint-managed process. For example, after starting a fresh REPL with `M-x` `comint-run` `python3`, evaluating `(process-send-string (current-buffer) "imp\t")` and then hitting RET will show that the underlying Python interpreter completed the `imp` to `import `.

Comment: As I explained, the example you provided is not how completions work in `comint` buffers. The details will depend on the process you run, and may be quite involved. In my package for interacting with the GRASS GIS program, the main completion function is [grass-completion-at-point](https://github.com/plantarum/grass-mode/blob/f17e330dfde6a1b81a9b33d019fc0dff890f482d/grass-mode.el#L718), and is 36 lines long. The package is 1200 lines long, and I wouldn't be surprised if 50% of that was completion support.

Comment: @Tyler 1) if you don't @ a commenter who is not the author of the question or answer being commented on, the commenter never knows you replied.

Comment: 2) "is not how completions work in comint buffers" seems logically orthogonal to what I said - what I commented simply ***is*** a thing that you can do to force some REPL processes to complete things, and thus inherently is one possible way that completions in comint buffers *could* be implemented. Maybe it's not the best way, maybe it's not how most (maybe even any) packages do it, and clearly it's not the way you do it in your package... and all that's fair, but that's not "as explained", because you *can* write code that sends individual raw tabs and acts on what the process writes back.

Comment: Or, phrased another way: "no single characters are passed directly" and "you can't rely on the native completion of the external program" are only partly true - you can pass single characters directly with your lisp code, and for some external programs you *could* rely on the native tab-completion if you wrote code to expect and parse it in the process output and then display it to the user (and you can trivially bind that code to the Tab key press or whatever). Having said that - I see now that what I was saying "would be great" was probably out-of-scope for (and orthogonal to) this answer.

Comment: Anyway, my disagreement and frustration with the seeming mismatch between assertions aside, +1 for this answer, now that I'm looking at it again, especially since your comment in reply to me helped clarify some useful bits.

Comment: @mtraceur while what you suggest is certainly *possible*, I don't think it's practical. Maybe I'm wrong, please submit your own answer if you can get this to work. But I suspect you'll run into a several complications that make it more involved than you expect. So involved that I think it would suggest an unproductive waste of time to people trying to follow this idea. Again, I'm happy to be proved wrong if you can put together something that ends up being more tractable than the conventional approaches.

Comment: @Tyler that's totally fair and you might be right. I only experimented a little so far: `(comint-send-input t) (process-send-string (current-buffer) "\t"))` in the `python3` REPL looks promising: something deep+early in `comint` swallows the reprint of the prompt, input, and any completion, but completion *candidates* from Python print as output and can be intercepted and parsed in `comint-preoutput-filter-functions`. In the `nodejs` REPL, `(comint-send-input t)` causes the process to exit; sending the same thing with raw `process-send-string` doesn't, but comint swallows all output.

Comment: (Ahh, `nodejs` process exit was because `comint-simple-send` was calling `process-send-eof` to the process when told to not append a newline.)

Comment: FYI, ESS uses completions provided by the underlying process. This looks like a good place to start (but with additional functions up and downstream to consider):

https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/d8914196ceb2061d850cc899aed79342519972ff/lisp/ess-r-completion.el#L233